# Return to answer after expanding a code snippet does not work properly

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I noticed a bug when you are using a code snippet's (aka "Stack Snippets") full page view (like **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47925880/1016343)**). You cannot navigate back by using the browser button, and a custom link does not work as expected.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd>.
2. On the upper right corner, click **"Full Page"**. This opens the full screen view.
3. The browser's "Go back" left arrow does not bring you back to the answer.
4. If you're using a hyperlink like `<a href="answer URL">Return to answer</a>` in your snippet to allow the user going back, then the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button disappeared. Reloading the page brings it back.

**Expected behavior:** Either allow to use the browsers left arrow button, or "repair" the issue with the disappearing <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button.

Comment: I have also faced the same issue.

Comment: Your reproduction steps are wrong imo, doing what you've done I get the `close` link in the top right. Did you mean clicking `expand snippet` and then running?

Comment: Voting on meta is different, @Matt. It is often used to express (dis)agreement. In this case, users probably think this ain't a bug.

Comment: @George - No, it is **not** Expand Snippet. Run the code snippet, then afterwards you get the "Full Page" link button.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Thanks, you helped already - I did not see the close action link in the upper right corner. Maybe a darker grey close button would be more visible? Not all people have young eyes ... and some have issues with low contrast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making a snippet fullscreen isn't a *"navigation"* action. It'd be illogical for that action to push an entry into your history. It's only logical that the browser's `[back]` button doesn't *"work"* like you described.

Just use the `[Close]` button on the top right of the maximized snippet:

[image]

Don't use *hacks* like that `"Return to Answer"` link.

Comment: I didn't see the close link, you are right!